# Tracking #tag usage across the website

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, looker-studio, custom-dimensions

I am implementing GA tracking for a big social content sharing platform, where users can use #tags for posts, comments etc. and I am looking for a way to correctly track how users use those tags across the website.

Website owner wants to measure:

- amount of posts with certain #tags
- amount of #tag mentions in comments under posts (which may be related to other #tags)
- amount of upvotes/downvotes on posts related to certain #tags

I was planning to use custom dimension "tag" and send its values whenever any tag-related action occurs, i.e. dim. value "bike" on a post where someone used a #bike tag. However there is a problem - most often actions that occur on the website are related to multiple tags simultaneously, i.e. a post with multiple tags, a pageview for one tag and a comment with another tag etc. Unfortunately, it is impossible to send multiple values for the same dimension at once.

Looking for answers, I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403334/universal-analytics-push-multiple-values-for-one-dimension-and-one-pageview#), where the best answer recommends to merge multiple values (#tags) for this dimension into one value, where strings (#tags) are separated by whitespaces. This solution allows to drilldown GA report statistics by using REGEX filtering. However the user must specify the #tag that he will use the REGEX filtering for. Therefore this solution lacks a very important feature - it makes it impossible to straightforward sort GA reports by metrics to get to know about trending popular #tags, that the website owners are not aware of (very important for them).

Can I use Data Studio calculated fields to somehow extract those #tags from the merged strings as a "tag" dimension value and calculate them separately?  Or maybe there is an another solution? I will appreciate any feedback, thanks!

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a db table for tags- this will give each tag an id. (And make it unique)
Then, Whatever data you want to collect, - can be your columns e.g 
 ID (primary key) | tag | post name | post id | Post category | user id | num upvotes | Timestamp | etc

Then, when running your reports -query the dB however you want to get which ever metric you want.

Comment: So I should use GA API to get 'tag' dimension values (merged strings) into the DB and then split those values into individual tags and allocate metrics, events etc. to those tags within the DB?

Comment: yes Use GA API for extraction. To transform the data only store the individual tags (split). you would then query that dbtable to get the metrics. if you have to store the metrics.. create another table where those aggregates will go. 
So your db has raw data [unique id(primarykey)] and tag | page | post | userid | whatever you want from GA... but no metrics here.. this is just stagging the data that you want... Then somewhere separate..  Query your table. 
select all bike tags in comments. 
Select all bike tags in posts. 
select posts with most bike tags.. etc