# Multi-dimensions not working at all as I thought

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

**EDIT**: It seems that according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21108458/11472579 this might not be possible, although they're not really the same usecase. Please let me know if this is the case.

I've been working on the past several days on and off trying to get my custom dimensions working.

I have a website for an app, the idea is:

- On the **front page**, we have **2** download buttons *(stable, preview)*
- On the **getting started** page, we have **2** download buttons *(stable,
  preview)*
- On our **forks** tab, we have **5** different forks, each with their own
  download button *(fork1, fork2).*

The thing I want to track (and thus, attach) is what is the name of the download *(appName, appName preview, fork1, fork2.. etc)* and what was the page it happened on.

So I have setup some several different GA send codes, but basically it looks like this (had other structures, all works the same):

```js
window.ga("send", "event", "Button", "Click", {
    'dimension1': this.$page.title, 'dimension2': this.$props.downloadName
});
```

Which translates to it sending:

`dimension1`: Home

`dimension2`: appName

`eventAction`: Click

`eventCategory`: Button

`hitType`: event

With this I want to setup a widget that displays this information, but it only ever gets replaced with old data. Let's say my dashboard widget only displays `appName: 23`, now a download to a fork happens, now it suddenly says `fork2: 24`.

But the thing is it's also *at times* displaying multiple `Page` stuff under the widget.
[Example of that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOcnS.png)

I'm actually going crazy over this, I really don't understand how I'm supposed to get the result as I want it.

Am I just missing something elementary?

I am asking of you sincerely, StackOverflow people, please help!

If you want a live enviroment for debugging, [I have an enviroment with a Netlify PR on](https://deploy-preview-143--tachiyomi.netlify.app/).

Comment: You forget to mention the most important: `what is the scope of your custom dimensions?` You should read the following article and report back with an updated question (scope + what doesn't work vs. expected behaviour) if things still don't work: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en

Comment: @max Sorry, I've tried using both `Hit` and `Session`, both still produce the wrong results.

Comment: -**Hit**: values will not get overwritten (each hit has its own data, subsequent hits won't change it). **Session**: yes, values will overwrite each other within the same session (you'll retain the last one). **If I were you I would test with a dummy property**: create 1 custom dimension of each scope (hit, session, user), send the data to all 3, do some tests, get the data back from GA, and report findings here if what you see deviates from the expected behaviour.